# multiple selection of NSPopUpButton

Tags: macos, cocoa, nspopupbutton, multipleselection

does any know how to make a NSPopUpButton with multiple selections which is like this.
[image]

Comment: Is that a `NSPopUpButton` or just a button with a menu?

Comment: I know it's 4 years later but did you ever find the answer?

Comment: Guy by the name of kevgski has an interestingblogpost in which he describes making NSPopUpButton reflect multiple values by setting the state of the relevant cells to NSControlStateValueMixed  https://sketchplugins.com/d/1246-setting-a-mixed-state-nspopupbutton. I imagine this would show the way to accomplish what @hodge wants.